# How do I commit first transaction after second transaction succeed in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to commit the first transaction after the second transaction succeed. 
Like ;
first transaction is called on selectIndexChanged and second on button click , and I want the first transaction(selectIndexChanged) to get commit when button click transaction succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `transaction` which is a part of command. Execute your both query using a single command it will work.

In your situation you need to keep the values in `session` on some where and letter execute both the queries using a single `command object`.

Comment: OK. I am thinking of using temporary table as I need to get some outputs from first transaction.